# Provide Multiple Theme Color For Android Application

Tags: android, dynamic, android-theme

I would to create an activity known as "Settings".

In this activity, I would like to provide 2 theme options which are either Dark or Light theme.

When user choose any of the theme color, it will automatically applied on it.

From my own googling, most tutorials would focus on 1 single activity instead.

Currently, I'm on these tutorial link http://www.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html

I'm abit confused at the part "Create Your Layout". How do I apply for all layouts/activity?

Answer (score 1):

Read further down.  You need to create theme switching code

> Create themeUtils.java header

Then you need to implement it

```
themeUtils.changeToTheme(this, themeUtils.BLACK);
```